# Remove button from subview in cell

Tags: ios, swift

i want to remove a button from a cell before reusing it. I am using:

```
func addImageToCell(image: UIImage, initialYCoordinate: CGFloat, initialHeight: CGFloat, initialXCoordinate: CGFloat) {

    imageButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as? UIButton
     ....
    self.contentView.addSubview(imageButton)

}
```

And to delete:

```
    if let image = self.imageButton {

        image.removeFromSuperview()
        self.imageButton = nil

    }
```

So, that works fine. But if there are more than one imageButtons, only the last one will be removed. I could use the same tag for each button, but i need the tag to identifer which imageButton is pressed.

I could also remove all buttons in subViews, but i have also other Buttons too which i dont want to delete.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you just make imageButton an array and remove all imageButtons?

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Can't you just hide the button instead of removing it?

Answer (score 1):

After `self.imageButton = nil` wrtie following line:

```
self.imageButton.removeFromSuperview()
```

i hope, these code works for you . . .